Error: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid opcode 13
I have class library works fine Asp.net but same class library used in mvc getting Error: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid opcode 13 in postman
I attached screenshot for reference
Asp.net Application hosted in IIS and tested in postman websocket.

MVC Application hosted in IIS and tested in postman websocket.

MVC controller:

